# How to find index of parent or children on nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am bit stuck in one solution

I have an nested array i would like to find and index of any parent or children using key id,
Here is sample json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "1.1",
        "name": "John doe 1.1"
      },
      {
        "id:": "1.2",
        "name:": "John doe 1.2"
      },
      {
        "id": "1.3",
        "name": "John doe 1.3",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "1.3.1",
            "name": "John doe 1.3.1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "Name": "Apple",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "2.1",
        "name": "Apple 2.1"
      },
      {
        "id:": "1.2",
        "name:": "Apple 1.2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find an index of parent or child array object to add children of that parent or child

so basically it will be nested array of n levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a flexible, iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [ { id: '1', Name: 'John Doe', children: [ { id: '1.1', name: 'John doe 1.1' }, { 'id:': '1.2', 'name:': 'John doe 1.2' }, { id: '1.3', name: 'John doe 1.3', children: [ { id: '1.3.1', name: 'John doe 1.3.1' } ] } ] }, { id: '2', Name: 'Apple', children: [ { id: '2.1', name: 'Apple 2.1' }, { 'id:': '1.2', 'name:': 'Apple 1.2' } ] } ];

const getNode = (data, id) => objectScan(['**(^children$).id'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'parent',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === id
})(data);
const getNodeWithParents = (data, id) => objectScan(['**(^children$).id'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'parents',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === id
})(data);

console.log(getNode(myData, '2.1'));
// => { id: '2.1', name: 'Apple 2.1' }
console.log(getNodeWithParents(myData, '2.1'));
/* =>
[
{ id: '2.1', name: 'Apple 2.1' },
[ { id: '2.1', name: 'Apple 2.1' }, { 'id:': '1.2', 'name:': 'Apple 1.2' } ],
{ id: '2', Name: 'Apple', children: [ { id: '2.1', name: 'Apple 2.1' }, { 'id:': '1.2', 'name:': 'Apple 1.2' } ] },
[ { id: '1', Name: 'John Doe', children: [ { id: '1.1', name: 'John doe 1.1' }, { 'id:': '1.2', 'name:': 'John doe 1.2' }, { id: '1.3', name: 'John doe 1.3', children: [ { id: '1.3.1', name: 'John doe 1.3.1' } ] } ] }, { id: '2', Name: 'Apple', children: [ { id: '2.1', name: 'Apple 2.1' }, { 'id:': '1.2', 'name:': 'Apple 1.2' } ] } ] ]
 */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 1):

Array.find or filter would do for the parent.

```
let found = data.find(each => each.id == '2');
console.log(found);
let foundChild = found.children.find(child => child.id == '1.2');
console.log(foundChild);
```

replace the find with filter

Comment: what if there are n levels ? it's not fixed json format

Comment: You mean n levels for the children?

Comment: Yes, children might have children inside it look at an example code there is one more children under 1.3 , 1.3.1 and 1.3.1 might have one more children 1.3.1.1 and so on

Comment: Basically i am using react state suppose i want to add children under 1.2 same time i also want state to be handled properly how do i do that?